# How to fix leaking accessor methods?

Tags: java, junit, bluej

so I am having trouble figuring out why my test in JUnit is failing. I have a `Bill` class, a `Money` class, and a `Date` class. A new `Bill` object is being created in the test and the line

```
assertTrue( myBill.getAmount().getCents() == 0);
```

is failing. So I am aware of where it is happening but I'm not exactly sure how to fix it. I have tried changing my mutator methods to things like

```
return new Date(dueDate);
```

instead of just

```
return dueDate;
```

but it is still failing in JUnit. Please help!

Test code:

```
@Test
public void testBillConstructorPrivacyLeak()
{
    Date date1 = new Date( 1, 1, 2020);
    Money money1 = new Money( 10);
    Bill myBill = new Bill( money1, date1, "sam");

    date1.setYear( 2021);
    money1.setMoney( 5, 10);

    //Now get values and make sure they have not changed
    assertTrue( myBill.getAmount().getCents() == 0);
    assertTrue( myBill.getDueDate().getYear() == 2020);
}
```

My classes:

```
public class Bill
{
private Money amount;
private Date dueDate;
private Date paidDate;
private String originator;

//paidDate set to null
public Bill (Money amount, Date dueDate, String originator) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.originator = originator;
    paidDate = null;
}

//copy constructor
public Bill (Bill toCopy) {
    this.amount = toCopy.amount;
    this.dueDate = toCopy.dueDate;
    this.paidDate = toCopy.paidDate;
    this.originator = toCopy.originator;
}

public Money getAmount () {
    return new Money(amount);
}

public Date getDueDate () {
    return new Date(dueDate);
}

public String getOriginator () {
    return originator;
}

//returns true if bill is paid, else false
public boolean isPaid () {
    return (paidDate != null);
}

//if datePaid is after the dueDate, the call does not update anything and returns false.
//Else updates the paidDate and returns true
//If already paid, we will attempt to change the paid date.
public boolean setPaid (Date datePaid) {
    if (datePaid.isAfter(dueDate)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        paidDate = new Date(datePaid);
        return true;
    }   
}

//Resets the due date – If the bill is already paid, this call fails and returns false. 
//Else it resets the due date and returns true.
public boolean setDueDate (Date newDueDate) {
    if (isPaid()) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        dueDate = new Date(newDueDate);
        return true;
    }
}

//Change the amount owed.
//If already paid returns false and does not change the amount owed else changes 
//the amount and returns true.
public boolean setAmount (Money amount) {
   if (isPaid()) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        amount = new Money(amount);
        return true;
    }
}

public void setOriginator (String originator) {
    this.originator = originator;
}

//Build a string that reports the amount, when due, to whom, if paid, and if paid 
//the date paid
public String toString () {
    return "Amount: " + amount + " Due date: " + dueDate + " To: " + "originator" + " Paid?" + isPaid() + "Paid date: " + paidDate; 
}

//Equality is defined as each field having the same value.
public boolean equals (Object toCompare) {
    if (toCompare instanceof Bill) {
        Bill that = (Bill) toCompare;
        return this.amount.equals(that.amount) && 
                this.dueDate.equals(that.dueDate) && 
                this.paidDate.equals(that.paidDate) && 
                this.originator.equals(that.originator);
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

```
public class Money
{   
private int dollars;
private int cents;

//Constructor which sets the dollar amount, and sets cents to 0
//If the user enters in an amount LT 0, you will throw an IllegalArgumentException
public Money (int dol) {
    if (dol < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
    this.dollars = dol;
    cents = 0;
}

//Constructor which initialized dollars and cents.
//If the user enters in an amount LT 0, you will throw an IllegalArgumentException
public Money (int dol, int cent) {
     if (dol < 0 || cent < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
    this.dollars = dol;
    this.dollars += cent / 100;
    this.cents = cent % 100; 
}

//Copy constructor
public Money (Money other) {
    this.dollars = other.dollars;
    this.cents = other.cents;
}

public int getDollars () {
    return dollars;
}

public int getCents () {
    return cents;
}

//If the user enters in an amount LT 0, you will throw an IllegalArgumentException
public void setMoney (int dollars, int cents) {
     if (dollars < 0 || cents < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
    this.dollars = dollars;
    this.dollars += cents / 100;
    this.cents = cents % 100; 
}

//Gets the money amount as a double
//For example it might return 5.75
public double getMoney () {
    return dollars + (cents / 100.0);
}

//If the user enters in an amount LT 0, you will throw an IllegalArgumentException4
public void add (int dollars) {
    if (dollars < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
    this.dollars += dollars;
}

//If the user enters in an amount LT 0, you will throw an IllegalArgumentException
public void add (int dollars, int cents) {
    if (dollars < 0 || cents < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
    this.dollars += dollars;
    this.cents += cents; 
    this.dollars += this.cents / 100;
    this.cents = this.cents % 100; 
}

//Adds the amounts in other to our money object – reducing cents appropriately.
public void add (Money other) {
    this.dollars += other.dollars;
    this.cents += other.cents; 
    this.dollars += this.cents / 100;
    this.cents = this.cents % 100;
}

//Two money objects are the same if they have the same value for dollars and cents.
public boolean equals (Object o) {
    if( o instanceof Money) {
        return this.dollars == ((Money)o).dollars && this.cents == ((Money)o).cents;
    }
    return false;
}

//Prints out the amount as a string IE “$3.75” or “$4.00”  Note the number of digits displayed for cents. 
//Again for testing and grading purposes use this EXACT output format
public String toString () {
    String c = String.format("%.02d",cents);
    return "$" + dollars + "." + c;
}
```

}

Comment: What does the test actually test? Does your code return the wrong value? Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see where the wrong value comes from?

Comment: It is testing to see if the values have changed (which they should not). But in the test it is assigning new values to it. The cents value should be 0 because it is set to 0 in the constructor in the Money class. But in the test it is setting it to 10 and therefore failing. I'm just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: And not very familiar with using the debugger. It is only failing because in JUnit it is being set to something else. There is nothing wrong with the class in itself. Until it gets changed from an outside source.

Comment: Show the source for the `Date` and `Money` classes.  Why does `Money` have a mutator if you expect the value to NOT change after calling it?  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I'm not really sure how else to phrase it...we were given methods that HAVE to be used in our classes and those included getters and setters. I added the Money class to the post because that is the test that is failing.

Comment: So privacy leaking is my problem because it allows someone to change the private instance variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem results from the fact that in your constructor for `Bill` you store *references* to the `Money` and `Date` objects.  Then, when you modify those objects in the test case you are modifying the same objects.

If you don't want that behavior you have to make a *deep copy* of the `Money` and `Date` objects in the `Bill` constructor, i.e.:

```
public Bill (Money amount, Date dueDate, String originator) {
    this.amount = new Money(amount);
    this.dueDate = new Date(dueDate);
    this.originator = originator;
    paidDate = null;
}
```

You don't have to do this for `originator` because Strings are immutable.

Comment: I tried changing "this.amount = toCopy.amount" to "this.amount = new Money(toCopy.amount)" and it didn't work...is there something else that I need to be doing?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong constructor... but yes that constructor will need to have the same change applied to it as well.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I was just doing it in the copy constructor rather than the original constructor. Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

<del>Although you do not show the implementation of your `Money` class</del>, the fact that it has a `setMoney` method suggests it's mutable. In that case, your problem is that `Bill`'s constructor isn't making copies of the objects it's passed in, and thus any changes to `money1` also change the state of `myBill`. Similar remarks apply to the `Date` objects.

Try modifying your code as follows:

```
public Bill (Money amount, Date dueDate, String originator) {
    this.amount = new Money(amount);  // needs copy-constructor for Money
    this.dueDate = new Date(dueDate); // likewise for Date
    this.originator = originator;     // no copying needed as String is immutable
    paidDate = null;
}

//copy constructor
public Bill (Bill toCopy) {
    // Make copies also in the copy-constructor
    this.amount = new Money(toCopy.amount);
    this.dueDate = new Date(toCopy.dueDate);
    this.paidDate = (toCopy.paidDate == null) ? null : new Date(toCopy.paidDate);
    this.originator = toCopy.originator;
}
```

In general, designing your objects to be mutable means you have to copy defensively in constructors and elsewhere.

On the other hand, designing your objects to be immutable is better as it avoids such problems (and is in fact the advice given by Joshua Bloch in his "Effective Java" book), but it turns out that Java doesn't help you a lot with them either and it's likely you'll struggle for quite some time with getting them done right.

My recommendation is for you to explore the http://immutables.github.io/ library for a better starting point with this design approach.

Answer (score 0):

When I am trying to replicate your code, I am getting error in this line:

```
public Date getDueDate () {
return new Date(dueDate);
}
```

Can you please tell what Date constructor you are using. As *java.util.date* has no such constructor which takes Date as an arguments.
Please elaborate so that I can proceed with debug and answer your query.

Thanks.

Comment: I actually figured it out already! But it is because I created my own Date class (part of the assignment requirement) instead of using Java's.